# Vyatta/EdgeOS remote access VPN without NAT?

Tags: vpn, nat, l2tp, vyatta, ubiquiti

I currently have a ubiquiti edgerouter setup with an ipsec site-to-site vpn and l2tp/ipsec remote access vpn. Both work as intended.

Is it possible to configure the remote access (l2tp/ipsec) vpn to work when the client is not behind NAT? I'm having trouble finding information about this since NAT is so prevalent and everyone assumes that it will be in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in contact with ubiquiti support and got this response:

> Unfortunately, it isn't possible  to configure the remote access VPN (L2TP/IPSEC) on Edgerouter to work when the client is not behind NAT.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this using OpenVPN instead, although you'd end up needing to install client software.  Assuming that the need is for something more secure than PPTP on the client end...